# How to identify multiple speakers from a single audio file in microsoft-cognitive

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am Working with the Speaker Recognition API, I have successfully enroll and identify a speaker. Now, I have multiple users speaking in an audio, How to identify multiple user from the audio?

Answer (score 1):

Speaker Recognition API only accepts single speaker's audio as input. If you have an audio including multiple speakers, please first separate the audio by speakers. Depending on your scenario, you can either use 2-speaker separation (diarization) feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription#speaker-separation-diarization) or use a specific microphone array setup with CTS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/conversation-transcription). The same speaker recognition technology is embedded in CTS that you don't need to make separate call to speaker recognition service.